# If $c$ is locally bounded and $\text P_x[X_s∈N,s<t]→1$ as $t→0$ for each nbhd $N$ of $x$, is $\text E_x[\frac1t\int_0^tc(X_s)\:ds]→\text E_x[X_0]$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

Let

- $E$ be a topological space with $\{x\}\in\mathcal B(E)$ for all $x\in E$ and $$\mathcal N(x):=\{N\subseteq E:N\text{ is an open neighborhood of }x\};$$
- $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ be a measurable space;
- $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ be an $E$-valued right-continuous process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$;
- $\operatorname P_x$ be a probability measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ with $$\operatorname P_x[X_0=x]=1\tag1$$ and $$\operatorname P_x[X_s\in N\text{ for all }s\in[0,t)]\xrightarrow{t\to0+}1\;\;\;\text{for all }N\in\mathcal N(x)\tag2$$ for $x\in E$;
- $c:E\to[0,\infty)$ be Borel measurable and locally bounded.

> Let $$Y_t:=\int_0^tc(X_s)\:{\rm d}s\in[0,\infty]\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0$$ and $$Z_t:=\operatorname E_x[Y_t]\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0$$ for some fixed $x\in E$.
>
> Are we able to show that $$\frac{Z_t}t\xrightarrow{t\to0+}\operatorname E[X_0]\tag3?$$

Note that we can easily show that $$\frac{Y_t(\omega)}t\xrightarrow{t\to0+}X_0(\omega)\tag4$$ for $\operatorname P$-almost all $\omega\in\Omega$.

Since $c$ is locally bounded, there is a $N\in\mathcal N(x)$ with $$c_N:=\sup_Nc\in[0,\infty).$$ Now, the idea is to apply the dominated convergence theorem. In order to do so, we need to find an $\operatorname P_x$-integrable for $\frac{Y_t}t$ for all $t\in(0,\delta)$ for some $\delta>0$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$. By $(2)$, $$\operatorname P_x[X_s\in N\text{ for all }s\in[0,t)]\ge1-\varepsilon\tag5\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[0,\delta)$$ for some $\delta>0$. Now, we may clearly write $$\frac{Y_t}t\le1_N(X_s)c_N+\frac1t\int_0^t1_{N^c}(X_s)c(X_s)\:{\rm d}s\tag6,$$ but is this helpful?

**EDIT**: Let $$\tau:=\inf\underbrace{\{t\ge0:X_t\in N^c\}}_{=:\:I}.$$ Since $N^c$ is closed, it holds for all $\omega\in\Omega$ either $\tau(\omega)\in I(\omega)$ or $I(\omega)=\emptyset$ and hence $\tau(\omega)=\infty$. We now see that $$\frac1tY_t\le c_N\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in(0,\tau)\tag7,$$ but is this enough?

**EDIT 2**: Since $x\not\in N^c$, we see that $\tau(\omega)>0$ for all $\omega\in\{X_0=x\}$ and hence for $\operatorname P_x$-almost all $\omega\in\Omega$.

Comment: I'm not sure what the role of $c$ is, or what $P_x$ really means, but perhaps modifying my example from before to $X_s = X_0 + sV$ for $V$ a nonnegative random variable with $E[V]=\infty$ would be a counter-example. The other answer was https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4495450/are-we-able-to-apply-the-monotone-convergence-theorem-to-show-that-frac1t-text

Comment: @Michael $\operatorname P_x$ is just a probability measure und which the set $\{X_0=x\}$ has probability $1$.

Comment: So to be clear, $E_x[X_0] = x$?

Comment: @user6247850 Since $E$ is a topological space and hence I don't know how you intend to define $\operatorname E_x[X_0]$, *no*. But if $E$ is a Banach space, *yes*.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I'm a little confused, then.  Why is $E[X_0]$ defined but not $E_x[X_0]$?  Also, to clarify, $P_x$ is _any_ probability measure such that $P_x(X_0=x) = 1$?

Comment: @user6247850 There was $c$ missing in the definiton of $Y_t$; it should be $$Y_t:=\int_0^tc(X_s)\:{\rm d}s$$ instead. Sorry!

Comment: @Michael Now I understand why you wrote that you're not sure what the role of $c$ is ... (see my comment above)

Comment: So the statement you're trying to show is that $\frac{Z_t}{t} \rightarrow E[c(X_0)]$ for every $x$?  Or there exists an $x$ such that that holds?  Or $\frac{Z_t}{t} \rightarrow E_x[c(X_0)]$ for some/every $x$?

Comment: Taking $c$ as the identity function and assuming $X_0$ and $V$ are independent random variables, and $E[V]=\infty$, doesn't $X_s = X_0 + sV$ act as a counter-example? For $\epsilon>0$, $x\in \mathbb{R}$, and $s>0$ we get $P[X_s \in (X_0-\epsilon, X_0+\epsilon)|X_0=x] = P[|V|<\epsilon/s]\rightarrow 1$ as $s\rightarrow 0^+$. And $Y_t/t= X_0+ Vt/2$ for all $t>0$, $E[Y_t/t|X_0=x]=\infty$ for all $t>0$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @user6247850 I want to show that for arbitrary $x$, $$\frac{Z_t}t\xrightarrow{t\to0+}\operatorname E_x[c(X_0)]=x.$$

Comment: @Michael What if we assume that $c$ is bounded? Then we can't take the identity function for $c$. Is there a still a counterexample?